# Images not loading in Next.js application after deploy on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm using tmdb movie API and using Next.js `getServerSideProps` method I call the API and fetch the data on my website.

On `localhost` everything is working fine, but when I deploy my website in Vercel the images do not load properly. The URL is shown like this `/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.tmdb.org%2Ft%2Fp%2Foriginal%2F%2F1g0dhYtq4irTY1GPXvft6k4YLjm.jpg%20&w=3840&q=75`. I don't know where is the `/_next?image` coming from.

Can somebody help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add more details? What does you `next.config.js` look like? And how are you using the `next/image` component?

Comment: module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images:{
    domains:["image.tmdb.org"]
  },
}

this Is my next.config.js code

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Could you also show your usage of the `Image` component?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the dir of your images and I had it before. Put all the images under `public/static/img` and create an image like below:

```
<img src={"/static/img/test.png"} alt="" />
```

Comment: Hi @Jamal! Thank you for the answer. but my images directly come from my API. I m not storing my images locally.i m using Next Image for images not <img>

Comment: Are the local images working?

Answer (score 0):

In case people are looking for answers to this problem of images not loading when Next.js application is deployed on Vercel in production, but able to load when running local and on preview deployments...

this is what worked for me. Add my own domain in the next.config.js under the images section

```
images: {
    domains: [
      'www.your-domain-name.com',
    ]
  },
```

Also means that adding the domain of your external sources might help? that is what worked for me.