# Images return 502 error after deploy project in vercel

Tags: vercel

I'm new in next js. i recently deployed my project to vercel. everything is working fine. but images are making errors as shown below

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()

image URL: https://portfolio-l2jkasia3-shafeequeot.vercel.app/_next/image?url=%2F..%2Fpublic%2Fimages%2Fnetflix.jpg&w=384&q=75

at the same time I have used import images. it is working fine after deploy

On localhost everything is working fine, but when I deploy my website to Vercel the images do not load properly.

images given as below
`<Image width={330} height={220}  className='object-fill w-44' src={key.image} alt={key.name}></Image>`

import images as below (it is working after deploy)

```
import Cover from '../public/cover.jpg'
<Image  className='object-fill w-44' src={Image} alt={key.name}></Image>
```

Can somebody help me?

i have referred this [Images not loading in Next.js application after deploy on Vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482151/images-not-loading-in-next-js-application-after-deploy-on-vercel)
but no luck

Comment: Images seem to be loading properly on the linked website. I don't see any failed images requests. Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: finally i given full link (https:website.com/public/image.jpg). This link is working since i could not find the proper way to fix the issue. if given src="image.jpg" images loading from local server. but when i deploy to vercel, images not loading

Comment: If that image is in the `public` folder then it should be referenced as `src="/image.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this issue and fixed it by dropping the ../public and just using the path to the image as if I was already operating inside the public folder.

Change the value of key.image to "/cover.jpg"

```
<Image  className='object-fill w-44' src={key.image} alt={key.name}></Image>
```

Comment: Thank you for comments.it was already inside ithe public folder

Comment: finally i given full link (https:website.com/public/image.jpg). it is working since i could not find the proper way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the img tag instead. This worked with my deployed(to Vercel) nextjs app.

Comment: Image tag is working. but what do for image optimization